# How to get correct autoref for theorems

Tags: hyperref, theorems

I have some own theorem environments. And my theorems are numbered like the chapter. Now I would like to use autoref with that. But it does not work like it is described here (http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html) with aliascnt. So how can I get that?

```
\documentclass[ngerman,halfparskip,12pt,pointednumbers]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,bbm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheoremstyle{absatz}
    {17pt}{10pt}{}{-1pt}{\scshape\bfseries}{.}{\newline}{}

\theoremstyle{absatz}

\newtheorem{satz}{Satz}[chapter]
\newtheorem*{satz*}{Satz}
\newtheorem{lemma}[satz]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollar}[satz]{Korollar} 

%\renewcommand*{\theoremautorefname}{Satz}
\begin{document}
\begin{satz}
\label{Satz}
text text theorem
\end{satz} 

In \autoref{Satz} we have shown...
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried this with the following example

`    \begin{satz}
    \todo{citation needed}
    \label{satz}
    theorem text
    \end{satz}
    In \autoref{satz} ...`

And of course this did not work, because of the \todo before the label. Just for anyone to remember, who stumbles upon this topic. (sorry I did not get a code environment working here.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`\autoref` requires the name of the environment in the form `\<name>autorefname` to work. So, in order to properly "auto reference" your `satz` theorem, you should use

```
\newcommand{\satzautorefname}{Satz}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[ngerman,halfparskip,12pt,pointednumbers]{scrreprt}
%\usepackage{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,bbm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheoremstyle{absatz}
    {17pt}{10pt}{}{-1pt}{\scshape\bfseries}{.}{\newline}{}

\theoremstyle{absatz}

\newtheorem{satz}{Satz}[chapter]
\newtheorem*{satz*}{Satz}
\newtheorem{lemma}[satz]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollar}[satz]{Korollar} 
\newcommand{\satzautorefname}{Satz}

\begin{document}
\begin{satz}
\label{Satz}
text text theorem
\end{satz} 

In \autoref{Satz} we have shown...
\end{document}  ​
```

Comment: Thanks that works. And with aliascnt it even works for Lemma and Korollar.

Comment: Why it is not work for me? I mean, when I use `\newcommand{\lemmaautorefname}{Lemma}`, then `\autoref{lem}`not work? OK, just use `thmtools` instead.

Comment: @user19832: I don't know. Can you supply something that replicates your issue in the form of a minimal example?

Answer (score 7):

I like all of my theorems etc numbered in sync with equations. For this I use the following macro to create my theorem-like environments:

```
% Some trickery to make \NewTheorem{} define theorem like environments
% work correctly with \autoref{}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\def\NewTheorem#1{%
  \newaliascnt{#1}{equation}
  \newtheorem{#1}[#1]{#1}
  \aliascntresetthe{#1}
  \expandafter\def\csname #1autorefname\endcsname{#1}
}
```

Then I define

```
\NewTheorem{Theorem}
\NewTheorem{Corollary}
```

etc and use `\begin{Theorem}...\end{Theorem}` etc in the text.

Note that the environment name (`Theorem`, `Corollary` etc) is the label that is used by `\autoref`.

Answer (score 3):

Here a somewhat "less professional" method that I find quite usefull and easy:

Load the `hyperref` package and insert the following in your preamble

```
\newcommand{\sref}[2]{\hyperref[#2]{#1 \ref{#2}}}
```

Now you can refer to anything by typing `\sref{<theorem_description>}{<label_name>}`. The `<theorem_description>` can be anything you want. I personally don't mind a solution like this because it requires almost no extra typing. Also it can be typed differenly in any situation, which I find quite usefull at the beginning of a sentence for instance.

Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\sref}[2]{\hyperref[#2]{#1 \ref*{#2}}}
\newtheorem{satz}{Satz}[section]
\newtheorem{folge}[satz]{Folge}

\begin{document}
\section{YOLO}

\begin{satz}\label{label1} Ein schoener Satz.
\end{satz}

\begin{folge}\label{label2}Wegen \sref{satz}{label1} folgt....
\end{folge}
\sref{Folge}{label2} has a capital, since it is the beginning of a sentence.

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Little downside would be the late decision to rename *Satz* to *Keks*, or rather Abbildung to Diagram (have seen this desire more often to rename something to Keks). You might find package `cleveref` interesting, tough.