# Cross-Referencing: equations, figures, and chapters, sections, etc

Tags: cross-referencing

When we reference equations, we can use `\eqref`, and when we reference figures, we can use `\fref`.  Then the reference for equation has `( )` and the word `figure` is inserted into the document locations.  Is there a reference for chapters, sections, subsections, subsubsections, etc?

This way when I reference the section, I can just do `\somethingref` instead `section~\ref`?

Comment: Have you seen the [cleveref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina From reading the documentation, I don't use `fancyref` or `hyperref` with `cleveref`.  Is that correct?

Comment: You can use `hyperref` and `cleveref`; just load `hyperref` *before* `cleveref`. As for `fancyref`, why use it if `cleveref` does a much better work?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina last questions: so `\cref{}` treats everything in `equation` and `displaymath` environments as equations but what about `align`?  If you want, you can make an answer with our previous comments and this one since I will be using `cleveref` now.  How does `\cref` now it is in a section argument?  Do I need to do `\cref{sec:}`? From my reading, I was under the impression the argument before the `:` wasn't needed in `cleveref`

Comment: Using cleveref you don't have to use any prefix. Simply use \label{text} and then \ref{text}. The package automatically detects the type of the referenced object and produces the correct string.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would suggest you [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) as another option. While `hyperref`'s `\autoref` is powerful, `\cref` (`\Cref`) from `cleveref` are more powerful and more easily customizable. Some comparisons:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}\label{chapter}
\section{Some Section}\label{sectiona}
\section{Some Other Section}\label{sectionb}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \rule{30mm}{20mm}
  \caption{Some Figure}\label{figure}
\end{figure}

Using \texttt{\textbackslash autoref}, we can refer to \autoref{chapter}, \autoref{sectiona}, and \autoref{figure}, but using a range fails:~\autoref{sectiona,sectionb}

Using \texttt{\textbackslash cleveref}, we can refer to \cref{chapter}, \cref{sectiona}, and \cref{figure}. \Cref{chapter}. \Cref{sectiona}. \Cref{figure}. A range has no problem now:~\cref{sectiona,sectionb}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You want the object name to be a part of the hyperlink? You can use the `nameinlink` option for `cleveref`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}\label{chapter}
\section{Some Section}\label{sectiona}
\section{Some Other Section}\label{sectionb}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \rule{30mm}{20mm}
  \caption{Some Figure}\label{figure}
\end{figure}

Using \texttt{\textbackslash autoref}, we can refer to \autoref{chapter}, \autoref{sectiona}, and \autoref{figure}, but using a range fails:~\autoref{sectiona,sectionb}

Using \texttt{\textbackslash cleveref}, we can refer to \cref{chapter}, \cref{sectiona}, and \cref{figure}. \Cref{chapter}. \Cref{sectiona}. \Cref{figure}. A range has no problem now:~\cref{sectiona,sectionb}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Want to change the default format for hyperlinks? Use `\crefdefaultlabelformat`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefdefaultlabelformat{[#2#1#3]}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}\label{chapter}
\section{Some Section}\label{sectiona}
\section{Some Other Section}\label{sectionb}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \rule{30mm}{20mm}
  \caption{Some Figure}\label{figure}
\end{figure}

Using \texttt{\textbackslash autoref}, we can refer to \autoref{chapter}, \autoref{sectiona}, and \autoref{figure}, but using a range fails:~\autoref{sectiona,sectionb}

Using \texttt{\textbackslash cleveref}, we can refer to \cref{chapter}, \cref{sectiona}, and \cref{figure}. \Cref{chapter}. \Cref{sectiona}. \Cref{figure}. A range has no problem now:~\cref{sectiona,sectionb}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

How about `\autoref` from the `hyperref` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}\label{chapter}

\section{Some Section}\label{section}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \rule{30mm}{20mm}
  \caption{Some Figure}\label{figure}
\end{figure}

Using \texttt{\textbackslash autoref}, we can refer to \autoref{chapter}, \autoref{section},
and \autoref{figure}.

\end{document}
```

For user defined environments such as Lemma, Proposition, etc., just define

```
\<env_name>autorefname
```

where `<env_name>` is the name of the environment you want to refer to. For details, see [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46262/18228).

Answer (score 1):

(Near) anything what you want. For example: `\def\somethingref#1{section~\ref{#1}}`. But if you love sections, it can be `\def\somethingref#1{My $\heartsuit$~section~\ref{#1}}`. :-)