# Is it possible to use \autoref without thmtools?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, amsthm, thmtools

I have the following tex file;

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{thm1}
Blah.
\end{thm}

Consider \autoref{thm1}.

\end{document}
```

With this set up, `\autoref{thm1}` prints "Theorem 1", but if I disable `thmtools`, it only prints "1". I was led to believe that `\autoref` is part of `hyperref` and should not require `thmtools`. Where am I going wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: you need to use `\newcommand{\thmautorefname}{Theorem}`, which is detailed in [How to get correct autoref for theorems](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46258) As such, I think this is a duplicate- let us know!

Comment: The hyperref "knows" about the `theorem` counter for Theorem-like environments, but not about other possible counters, such as `thm`. If you choose counters other than `theorem`, you need to supply your own supplemental `\...autorefname` macros.

Comment: Thanks, that worked and this is probably a duplicate. Sorry!