# How to label equations effectively and efficiently?

Tags: equations, labels

I am writing a thesis containing a lot of equations. One problem I am facing is how to label them well enough so that it is easier to refer to them later on. Currently, I tried to name every equation. This method works fine, but it is cumbersome and inefficient. I am wondering whether anyone has a good way to label things. In particular, I am curious how editors label tons of equations in math books. Thank you!

[To a moderator, please allows this question. Labeling equations in a useful way (and not just in such a way that it simply works!) is a very common problem that requires experience or advice. Of course, would be better if the author could pose a question in a more specific fashion but I think throwing it into the bin means introducing a negative selection process. You allow super-specific questions which are easy to formulate nicely but are of interest only to a very, very small number of people. Then you throw away a question that is relevant to literally almost every person on a planet that starts a Ph.D. in subjects such as math or computer science.]

Comment: You only have to `\label` those that you want to `\ref`. But that's not the question, correct?

Comment: You can use `\label{eq:bla:foo:bar}` which is an abbreviation of first it refers to an equation then roughly the topic name, the approximate location in terms of section so on

Comment: @Werner I do have a lot of cross-reference to do. But you just reminded me that maybe I should try to use less cross-reference.

Comment: Personally, I name them eq1, eq2, etc.  What good is a label if I can't remember what the heck it is?  And yes, when I add, remove or rearrange equations, I go back and rename them.  I used to just tag them myself until I discovered hyperref would link \ref{}s to \label{}s.

Comment: I label all of my equations (theorems, lemmas, ...) with labels of the form `E:desciption`,  (`T:description`, `L:description`,...) where `description` describes the equation/theorem/lemma/....  My editor (vim), expands these labels via tab-completion, this makes it easy to find the right label. You may also find it helpful to use the [showkeys package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showkeys). I also recommend using `\autoref` from the [hyperref package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and the technique in [How to get correct autoref for theorems](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46258)

Comment: @Andrew Thanks. What do you mean by tab-completion, please? How to do it?

Comment: @LaTeXfan You can set up vim so that the tab key causes partially typed text to expand into various commands, macros or even environments. Look for `expandtab`, `listchars` in the vim documentation. The latex ftplugins for vim implement explicit latex-style tab completions but you can do this "by hand" by throwing what you want (`\alpha`, `\beta`, `...`) into a custom dictionary. For tab completion, I highly recommend the vim [supertab](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=182) and [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) plugins.