# \autoref from hyperref not showing correct theorem label

Tags: hyperref, labels, autoref

I am writing some lecture notes for a course on overleaf.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem*{notation}{Notation}
\newtheorem*{note}{Note}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}

\def\bse{\begin{equation*}}
\def\ese{\end{equation*}}
\def\bp{\begin{proposition}}
\def\ep{\end{proposition}}
\def\bt{\begin{theorem}}
\def\et{\end{theorem}}

\begin{document}

%some text

\bt
\label{t:theorem_bla}
bla
\et

\bp
\label{p:deg}
Let $K\ss L$ be fields and let $\a \in L$ be algebraic over $K$. Then:
\bse
[K(\a):K]=\deg P_{min}(\a,K) \, .
\ese
\ep

%some more text

Hence, by \autoref{p:deg}, we have:

%even more text

\end{document}
```

I just recently found out about the `\autoref` command provided by the `hyperref` package. Quite pleased with it, it worked fine showing the correct label for my custom theorem environments (lemmas, prepositions, etc.).
However, I realised that at some point all the labels appeared as "Theorem" instead. I don't recall making any changes to the preamble in that short amount of time. Also, I have read this question:
[How to get correct autoref for theorems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46258/how-to-get-correct-autoref-for-theorems)
However, I didn't have `\<name>autorefname` in the preamble before and it worked...
I have tried to compile it on my MiKTeX and I get the same output, so this doesn't seem to be related to Overleaf.

Comment: `\autoref` detects the entity by the counter name in the anchor name of the reference. If different types of entities share the same counter, then `\autoref` cannot distinguish them. Packages like `aliascnt` might help to created different fake counters, which share the same counter, but make `\autoref` happy because of the different counter names. Of course, the new counter names needs support by `\<name>autorefname`.

Comment: Please strip down the example on overleaf and post it here. Code on external sites might vanish at some time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem arises because the `theorem`, `corollary`, `definition`, `lemma`, and `proposition` environments all share the same counter.

The quickest solution I can think of is to (a) add the instruction

```
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
```

after loading the `hyperref` package and (b) replace all instances of `\autoref` with `\cref`.

Aside: I can't help but remark that your document suffers from a gross overuse of `\left` and `\right` to autosize the "fence symbols" (parentheses, brackets, etc.). In many cases I've looked at, omitting the `\left` and `\right` instructions would definitely be the (typographically) correct thing to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and thanks for the remark as well. May I just ask for clarification, do you think I should remove (most of) the \left \right instructions? Is there a good reference that you can suggest about mathematical typography?

Comment: @DemK. - I'd say you only time you need the non-default size of the fences in the document you've posted is when you're encasing a `\sum...` statement in parentheses in a display-math environment. In these cases, I'd use `\biggl(` and `\biggr)`, as `\left(` and `\right)` would give you parentheses that are too large, typographically speaking. For an excellent introduction to mathematical typography using the TeX system, I can heartily recommend chapters 16 to 19 of *The TeXbook* by Don Knuth.

Comment: Thank you very much for your tips and the recommendation.

Comment: @DemK. - Do also replace all instances of `_{min}` with `_{\min}`, don't redefine `\det`, `\diag`, `\gcd`, and under no circumstance redefine `\rm`. (It's a good thing you don't actually use `\rm` in your document...)